# Binding listbox from another project class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

How can i bind a property ObservableCollection, to xaml listbox.
Collection is in another project. I already have datacontext = this for second property.

I have some project Data, there is a class with property ObservableCollection Values. I need to bind it to mainwindow's xaml listbox Values.

Comment: Consider adding some of your code

Comment: Hi, can you please put a bit more information into your question. It should at least contain some xaml markup, code-behind (and view model, model classes).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view model that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged)

you can add an additional property that wraps the property in your other class, you would then need to bind to this property e.g.

```
        const string MY_COLLECTION = "MyObservableCollection";

        ObservableCollection<someType> _myObservableCollection;

        public ObservableCollection<someType> MyObservableCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _myObservableCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == _myObservableCollection) return;
                _myObservableCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(MY_COLLECTION);
            }
        }
```

In your xaml set your binding to yourDataContext.MyObservableCollection, in your (e.g) constructor for your view model set the property to your other observable collection i.e.

```
MyObservableCollection = OtherClass.OtherObservableCollection
```

Obviously their types will need to match